# Display Enum as Key-Value pair JSON

Tags: c#, enums

I have an ENUM as shown below. I need to display the Key - Value pair of it. I have shown how I need to see the output.

```
public enum CourseEnum
{
    Science= 1, 
    Math =2, 
    English=3, 
    History=4
    
}
```

The out put

```
{
    "1" : "Science",
    "2" : "Math ",
    "3" : "English",
    "4" : "History"
           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you can cast your enum to dictionary and then convert it to json:

```
var dict = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CourseEnum))
               .Cast<CourseEnum>()
               .ToDictionary(t => (int)t, t => t.ToString());
```

And using `Newtonsoft`:

```
var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

Answer (score 1):

See the code snippet. Adjust it to your needs:

```
foreach (var e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CourseEnum)).Cast<CourseEnum>())
    Console.WriteLine($"\"{(int)e}\" : \"{e}\"");

// output:
"1" : "Science"
"2" : "Math"
"3" : "English"
"4" : "History"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can like this.

```
var data = Enum
            .GetNames(typeof(CourseEnum))
            .Select(name => new
            {
                Id = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(CourseEnum), name),
                Name = name
            })
            .ToArray();
```